# Find possible routes to locate a number in a tree

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic, binary-search-tree

**Prompt :** 
Assuming there is a binary search tree that stores the integers from 1 to 1000 and we are looking for the number 363. Which of the following sequences of nodes CANNOT  be applied to the tree?
a. 2,252,401,398,330,344,397,363 
b. 924,220,911,244,898,258,362,363 
c. 925,202,911,240,912,245,363
d.2,399,387,219,266,382,381,278,363
d. 2 ,399,387,219,266,382,381,278,363
e. 935,278,347,621,299,392,358,363

Thanks for any help.I really need it.

Comment: Talk us through your reasoning. What have you tried so far? Also, is this for a class? If so, what is the class's policy on asking for help online?

Comment: @templatetypedef, yes , this is for a data structures class. I am going to be examined for the summester and this is a problem that was at the test some years ago. You don't really need to write any code to answer .

Comment: @Considering that any binary search tree node has two children and the left one has a less value than the root and the right one has a greater value than the root , I tried to apply preorder, postorder and inorder and see which one of the algorithms for every sequence doesn't refer to a tree that keeps that rule.

Comment: @templatetypedef , I forgor to tag you one my previous comment.

Comment: I don't believe this problem involves inorder/preorder/postorder traversals. It's about the sequence of values you'd see along a lookup. Have you tried constructing (partial) BSTs for which those lookup sequences could happen? If so, what did you find?

Comment: Hint: draw a path paying attention to whether each edge goes to the left or to the right. Then build and draw a new BST by inserting each vertex in the path in order, from top to bottom.  Do you get identical drawings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem will be in the last option (e) wherein the binary search property gets violated - it doesn't hold for nodes 347 and 299 since 621 is a right child of 347, all nodes to the right of 347 are supposed to be greater than itself, but 299 isn't.

Hope the below image clarifies.

[image: The binary search property doesn't hold for the nodes 347 and 299]

Comment: thank you for you nice answer ! One last question, is there a formula for this check ?